# Step fade Infinite Scroll appending of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, infinite-scroll, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope's Masonry layout alongside Infinite Scroll, which is initiated by clicking a button.

I want to animate/transition each .article item into place, however I am only able to achieve this via CSS on the initial layout. Is there a way of creating this 'step fade' effect each time the infinite scroll function is run?

Many thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="articles">
    <div class="article">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.articles').imagesLoaded(function () {
    // vars
    // Define grid
    var $grid = $('.articles');

    $grid.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.article',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        transitionDuration: 0,
        stagger: 500,
        hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 },
        visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 }
    });

    var iso = $grid.data('isotope');

    // Init infinite scroll
    $grid.infiniteScroll({
        path: '.pagination .next a',
        append: '.article',
        outlayer: iso,
        loadOnScroll: false,
        scrollThreshold: false,
        button: '.load-more-button',
        hideNav: '.pagination',
        status: '.load-status',
    });         
});
```

Comment: What is the 'infinite scroll function'? your question not clear enough.. can you explain more what you need to be done?

Comment: @SeReGa it is like an infinite zoom

Comment: Post an example of your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Have a look at https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/QgMWzV/ from: https://infinite-scroll.com/extras.html#loading-json

Answer (score 3):

It seems that You're very close.

If You want each of the newly loaded item to slide in with a fade, just modify Your masonry init code:

```
$grid.isotope({
   itemSelector: '.article',
   layoutMode: 'masonry',
   stagger: 500,
   visibleStyle: { transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 },
   hiddenStyle: { transform: 'translateY(100px)', opacity: 0 }
});
```

Your infinite scroll code

```
var $container = $grid.infiniteScroll({
    path: '.pagination .next a',
    append: '.article',
    outlayer: iso,
    loadOnScroll: false,
    scrollThreshold: false,
    button: '.load-more-button',
    hideNav: '.pagination',
    status: '.load-status',
});
```

And here's the logic to load more on a button click:

```
viewMoreButton.on( 'click', function() {
  // load next page
  $container.infiniteScroll('loadNextPage');
});
```

And it should work.

Take a closer look at official infiniteScroll library example usage with masonry and with buttons.

- https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/eRRQVo
- https://infinite-scroll.com/#masonry-isotope-packery
- https://infinite-scroll.com/extras.html#button-behaviors